# Spark Left Join is giving error of ambiguoes Column Name even though using dataframe name when selecting

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

```
sender_df = user_df.join(sender_df, user_df.contactno == sender_df.senderno, how='left')
```

sender_df = [contactno: string, senderno: string, time: time, reciverno: string, type: int]
user_df = [contactno: string, fname: string, lname: string, address: string]

Consider above dataframes. sender and user both is having contactno field. Now when i left join them using above mentioned field it is giving me ambigues columns contactno error. But i am not selecting any field and in join condition also i am mentioning dataframe.field. Still facing the issue. On both user and sender df some transformation has been applied before join.

Need help to understand what is going on under the hood and why i am facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error arises later when you have two columns named contactno. Is that possible? You can rename one of them, as it is not possible to work further with a dataframe where two columns have the same name.